# How to find the element using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can't find the element of the html below.

```
<span class="tabComboBoxName" id="tab-ui-id-1565209097494" aria-hidden="true">20/07/2019</span>
```

I've tried the following codes:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//class[@id='tab-ui-id-1565209097494']")
elem = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tabComboBoxName')
elem = browser.find_elements_by_id('tab-ui-id-1565209097494')
```

For those tries I got an empty list.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page you are trying to scrape please?

Comment: I can't send the link because its a Tableau Dashboard then I need to send user and password.

Comment: Okay, well my guess is that what you are after is dynamically generated. Load the page, and then right click view source. Then hit ctrl-f and paste in 'tabComboBoxName' and tell me if it finds it in the source code.

Comment: @RobertKearns You are right, I can't find the "tabComboBoxName"

Comment: The 1565209097494 looks like a timestamp FYI, so don't go by that.

Answer (score 1):

The element is a dynamically generated element so to locate the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.tabComboBoxName[id^='tab-ui-id-']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='tabComboBoxName' and starts-with(@id, 'tab-ui-id-')][contains(., '20/07/2019')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @RafaelSchettini How about the _xpath_?

Comment: @RafaelSchettini _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: the element is hidden

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the element doesn't belong to an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), if it does - you will need to [switch_to()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) the iframe where the element lives prior to attempting to find it
2. Make sure that the element doesn't belong to [ShadowDOM](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TDB/SeeTestAutomation+-+Mobile+Web+Testing+On+Chrome+With+Android), if it does - you will need to locate the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) element, cast it to the [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) and use [find_element()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) function of the **WebElement** instead of **driver**
3. Make sure to use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as it might be the case the element is not immediately available and it's being loaded later via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request
4. Try using another [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies), for instance you can stick to the element text like:

   ```
   //span[text()='20/07/2019']
   ```